# How many ways dividing $n$ balls into $3$ buckets with limitations?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

### Problem

> How many ways dividing $n$ balls into $3$ buckets with the following
>   limitations(?):
>
> - 1st bucket contains **odd** number of balls.
> - 2nd bucket contains a **multiplication of 4** number of balls.
> - 3rd bucket contains either **0** or **2** balls exactly.

I'm trying to solve this problem using Generating Functions.

### Solution

Lets find the generating functions using the above limitaions:
$$(x+x^3+...)(1+x^4+x^8+...)(1+x^2) = x(1+x^2 +...)(1+x^4 + ...)(1+x^2)$$
$$= x (1+x^2) \frac{1}{1-x^2} \frac{1}{1-x^4}$$

Now is the point I get stuck. What should I do next? Should I find the coefficient of $x^n$? If so, how?

Comment: You can simplify the problem considerably by noting that all remainders mod $2$ are fixed, so $n$ must be odd and you can put the odd ball in the first bucket and then distribute the rest of the balls in pairs -- the constraints then become 1. no constraint, 2. even number, 3. 0 or 1 balls. Also note that you didn't count $0$ as a multiple of $4$ in your generating function (which it is).

Comment: @joriki: Using your suggestion I don't even need to use generating functions, am I? (I've edited the question to count 0 as multiple of 4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eliminating the common factor $(1+x^2)$ from the numerator and denominator, you have
$$
x\left(1-x^2\right)^{-2} = x \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{(k+1) x^{2k}} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{(k+1)x^{2k+1}} = \sum_{\text{odd } k}\frac{k+1}{2}x^k.
$$
So, looking at the coefficient of $x^n$, there are $\frac{n+1}{2}$ ways to legally divide the balls if $n$ is odd, and none if $n$ is even.

Comment: can you please elaborate on how you done the last transition ?$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{(k+1)x^{2k+1}} = \sum_{\text{odd } k}\frac{k+1}{2}x^k$$

Comment: It's a change in the summation variable.  Define $k'=2k+1$.  Then $k+1=(k'+1)/2$, and when $k=0,1,2,...$, the new variable $k'=1,3,5,...$.  Then rename $k'\rightarrow k$.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude 0 as a multiple of 4 (which just gives the factor of $x^4$) you can finish your calculation by using $1-x^4=(1-x^2)(1+x^2)$ and then finding the coefficients of $\frac 1 {(1-x^2)^2}$ by using

$$(1-x)^{-2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^n.$$

Comment: Trying to generalize the solution:
Get the generating function to one of the [familiar forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Ordinary_generating_functions) and use it to find the coefficient.
True?

Comment: I don't want to exclude 0 as a multiple of 4, it was a mistake. I edited the question to fix it.